# Possible to Change Date to Day Week in CRM Chart by xml

Tags: xml, charts, crm, dashboard

I have created  a chart that displays data for each day
Just wondering if it possible to change the axis label from the Date like it is in this chart to Day of week.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Hi how are you wanting the date to look? For example are you hoping it would come out like Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...?

Comment: @Jason, yes Monday, Tuesday ,Wednesday....